# Why, if at all, do municipal governments in the US not seek to spread out immigration?

Tags: united-states, immigration, republican-party, illegal-immigration, new-york

Recently, the Republican governors of many states in the USA have been pursuing a strategy of sending immigrants to specific cities with Democratic governments. While the reception has been mostly welcoming, some of these cities' leaders and residents have reacted negatively to the perceived unsustainability of the increased immigration, such as Eric Adams, the mayor of New York, who recently traveled abroad to attempt to persuade people not to immigrate to the city.

However, there does not seem to have been much of an effort to provide assistance to immigrants in moving to surrounding cities and suburbs elsewhere in the same state, thus spreading out the strain on the social safety nets of the cities over a larger area and a larger number of taxpayers. Is this the case, and if so, what political or practical reasons underpin it?

Comment: Most services like Healthcare, unemployment, etc. are funded by the state (most cities, unlike NYC, do not collect their own income taxes) so moving them to different cities in the same state does not change the math.

Comment: Many of the places in US, as you have mentioned, are *suburbs* of individual houses with a specific price tag. How do you move immigrants in there if that price tag is not available to them and aid programmes do not cover it?

Comment: @uberhaxed - The general impression I get seems to be that some of these city governments are concerned about their ability to provide adequate housing because of shelter capacity requiring them to pay for expensive alternate housing. That seems, at least superficially, to be a city-level problem that could be mitigated by helping people spread out.

Comment: @alamar - The cities that are being targeted are typically very populous with a high cost of living. Their suburbs tend to be less appendages of housing complexes and more smaller cities with as many apartment buildings as free-standing houses, if not more, and typically have lower housing prices. They also have their own shelter programs.

Comment: Cities do not typically run housing programs (most programs are federal), likely due to lack of tax to support this, and the ones that do (for example, NYC) seem to have such stringent eligibility requirements that the housing program is not affected by illegal immigrants because they cannot use it (and this does not affect the supply of housing).

Comment: @Obie2.0 You cannot spread out immigration evenly but I guess the "best" you could do: move it out of poorest and most cramped areas of large cities, into already poorest and most cramped upstate towns, and/or towns with no jobs at all.

Comment: @Obie2.0 This question is confusing. You're conflating immigration with illegal immigration. That sole fact remains a massive part of the entire situation which your question ignores. Are you asking why New York state wont accept illegal immigrants from New York City? Are you asking why sanctuary cities don't bus the migrants to each other? Only two states allow illegal immigrants statewide. Without more specific information, its hard to answer what is being asked. Please reference this link as it may help answer your question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanctuary_city

Comment: @DavidS: Sanctuary cities are completely irrelevant to this topic. A sancturary city does not use city resources to help the federal government enforce federal immigration law. But the people at issue in this question are allowed by the federal government to stay in the US while their cases are pending. So it makes no difference for them whether a city helps federal government enforce federal immigration law.

Comment: @user102008 The question specifies municipal governments, which sanctuary cities are. I would encourage you to reread the question.

Comment: @DavidS: I have read the question, and I know that sanctuary cities are municipal (by definition). My points stands that whether a city is a sanctuary city or not is irrelevant for the purposes of this question, since the definition of sanctuary city relates to the city's assistance in immigration enforcement, but the people in question are not currently subject to deportation.

Comment: "perceived unsustainability"? Do houses, roads, schools, fully staffed hospitals/clinics, and infrastructure just spring up out of nowhere? That's not a perception. That's just the real world reality that you can't just drop a bunch of people into a local/regional social system and expect the accompanying social support entities to just magically appear out of thin air. That takes planning, investment, and time on the order of years to work out.

Answer (score 5):

State and local government have basically no legal authority over immigration, which is exclusively the province of the federal government. They have no authority to tell immigrants, documented or undocumented, to go somewhere else, or to prevent them from going somewhere else.

There is very little that municipal governments have the authority to do other than to provide services to a sudden influx of people. And, so far, most of the responses that have occurred have been responses to exigent states of emergency with large number of people in a distressed state, rather than anything that they have had much of a chance to respond to in the longer term.

Also, from a political perspective, Democratic cities have been disinclined to treat migrants as pawns by passing the buck to someone else as their Republican political counterparts have done. Indeed, in some cases, depending upon the facts, the approaches taken by Republican governors to send migrants elsewhere may be illegal or even criminal conduct.

Comment: The first paragraph seems to be a non sequitor. The question doesn't suggest that these sanctuary states should send the immigratnts somewhere else. Just spread them out among cities within the state, rather than trying to house them in a single city.

Comment: @ohwilleke, I personally think those in our federal government who have for a long time turned a blind eye to millions of people sneaking across our southern border over the past few years, and decided to keep silent about this mass intrusion, is something that is more criminal than the act of Republican governors busing undocumented people to various places around the nation.

Comment: @Barmar They don't have authority to spread people out or move them anywhere.

Comment: @user57467 Your opinion on this point isn't on topic to either the question or the answer.

Comment: May depend on the state. In MA, right-to-shelter is a state law, not a per-city mandate, so the state is taking control.

Answer (score 0):

New York City has a ["right to shelter"](https://www.coalitionforthehomeless.org/our-programs/advocacy/legal-victories/the-callahan-legacy-callahan-v-carey-and-the-legal-right-to-shelter/) mandate as a result of a consent decree in 1981 (Callahan v. Carey). So if a huge number of homeless immigrants show up in the city, they have to find a place to house them. I don't think this allows them to force the immigrants to move to other cities.

So their best approach to mitigate this problem is to try to reduce the number of migrants coming to NYC in the first place.

If this mandate had been applied at the state level rather than on the city itself, perhaps it would be possible to distribute migrants to shelters in different cities, easing the burden of any single city. But that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: "their best approach to mitigate this problem is to try to reduce the number of migrants coming to NYC in the first place." How could NYC possibly do that?

Comment: _c.f._ Massachusetts, where there is a statewide right to shelter for families with children under [G. L. c. 23B s. 30](https://malegislature.gov/Laws/GeneralLaws/PartI/TitleII/Chapter23B/Section30).

Comment: @ohwilleke Apparently, by sending their mayor on a worldwide PR tour. Success has yet to be determined.

Comment: @ohwilleke Mayor Adams went on a trip to Latin America and told them that coming to NYC would be a nightmare. Whether it will work is debatable, as being homeless in NYC is probably better than their lives back home.

Comment: @Barmar Sounds dubious to me. And what Mayor wants to tell the world that his city is a shitty place to live for a significant number of people who live there.

Comment: @ohwilleke He's really trying to thread a needle, since he's also trying to advertise it as a great place for tech companies to relocate. But he's not saying it's a shitty place for everyone, just if you're homeless, which will be the situation for any migrants.